# Локализация для бота Дискорд, как мне получить discord.locale?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Локализация для бота Дискорд, как мне получить discord.locale?
Строки отвечающие за получения языка:

```
def get_locale(member):
    return member.locale
i18n.init_bot(bot, get_locale)
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, свойство locale у объекта User есть только если User был получен через OAuth2, а не обычного бота. Я бы порекомендовал сделать локализацию по-серверно, а не по-пользовательно, т.к. пользователей очень много, и база данных может не выдержать (хотя в наше время такое случается редко).

Comment: @твояdeadline, Я как раз в документации прочитал про ClientUser.locale, оно мне выдает <member 'locale' of 'ClientUser' objects>, как мне это приобразовать в str?

Comment: @твояdeadline, или я как то могу по другому получить язык пользователя от клиента автоватически?

Comment: "Автоматически", как вы выразились, никак. Получить локализацию пользоваетеля можно только через OAuth2. Вот пример на гитхабе..
https://github.com/discord/discord-oauth2-example/
и пример результата:
https://prnt.sc/213go1d

Comment: @твояdeadline, спасибо